# jQuery onclick call function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found a [script](https://github.com/Matt-Webb/jquery-quiz-using-json) that converts json file into quiz using jquery.

I am playing with it's code for almost a day now and I can't come with what I wanted to have.

Functions    `quiz().init();` and `quiz().bindSubmit();` are called when page loaded.

What I want is the **START** button must be clicked first to load the Quiz.

```
$("#start").click(function(){
    currentQuestion = 0;
    questionCount = 0;
    answerArray = [];
    infoMode = false;
    gotData = false;
    inMemoryData = [];
    quiz().init();
    quiz().bindSubmit();
});
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
<div id="quiz-content"></div>
```

It works at first click of **START** button also in the next clicks, it successfully reset the quiz and goes back to #1.

But the problem is after the first click of **Start Button**, the quiz won't work normally when submitting the quiz. The quiz began to stucked in #1.

For better understanding, [JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/t4p8x02b/34/).

Edited:
Basically when the user click start button more than once,the quiz gets started from the beginning ,but didn't get to the next question(Gets stuck on the 1st question itself)

Comment: at the end it's confusing statement, I could not understand because you say it's working and next you said it's not

Comment: your code on jsfiddle works just fine on my browser. im use chrome btw.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili The problem is after the first click of Start Button, the quiz won't work normally when submitting the quiz. The quiz began to stucked in #1. Try to press Start button from two or three times then try to answer the quiz.

Comment: @YosiAzwan have you tried to click the start button multiple times? and then try to answer the quiz. It will stuck to #1

Comment: yes, I see, its cycling first question

Comment: @Jacob: Did you check my answer?

Comment: yes, i finished quiz and get this : Start

Quiz Complete

The Occasional Strutter

You don’t mind doing the occasional strut in your underwear to retrieve your jeans from the dryer, but you’d rather avoid it. You follow the ten-second rule when food drops on the floor, and you aren’t scare bla bla bla,
Your score was: 15

Total questions: 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `bindSubmit` function, inside it you are attaching to the `submit` event of the `#quizForm`. So when you press **Start** button twice, there two event handlers attached to the same event and that is because it is not behaving as it should be. So inside the `bindSubmit` function you need always disconnect all `submit` handlers (`$(document).off('submit');`), like this:

```
var bindSubmit = function () {
  $(document).off('submit');
  $(document).on('submit', '#quizForm', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    next(this);
    quiz().init();
  });
};
```

Here is your original fiddle with mentioned update
https://jsfiddle.net/t4p8x02b/35/

Comment: You're a superhero! It works, thanks!!! Would you consider this as the best solution?

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome. For that script I think it is ok. What is important, especially when dealing with event handlers, is to always disconnect them when they are not needed anymore.

Comment: I've added it to my project, unfortunately, when I click start button, it's refreshing the page.

Comment: Check your html, whether you are not submitting the entire page because of some invalid html. Or try to `return false;` inside the `$("#start").click` function. When it works in the fiddle it should also work in your page.

Comment: Fixed it. Found out that it affects other forms to refresh when it is submitted. I think it's because of `$(document).off('submit');` other forms also has `preventDefault();` but still refreshing. When I tried to remove the `off('submit')`, other forms can be submitted without refreshing the page. Any help? I tried `$(document).on('submit');` when submitting other forms but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things i observed in your code, which needs to be rectified for better management of code:

- There is no need to expose `init()` outside your `quiz` library, for first time initialization, you can call `init()` before your return from the library(end of quiz() module code).
- Also exposing `init()` makes your `quiz()` module vulnerable since it can be modified by any external program which could spoil your entire `quiz()` logic.
- Inside `bindSubmit()`, you dont need to re-initialize your quiz instance to call `init()`, rather just call `init()`(refer below code snippet), your event handler will call it without any error **[This is the magic of Closure]**.

**bindSubmit():**

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#quizForm', function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         next(this);
         init();
    });
```